# Local execution of program does not requre carriage return. Remote execution does?

Tags: c++, psexec

I've got a simple executable which begins by checking for a command line argument, some simple initialization, and then a status message.

```
if (argc != 2)
{
    std::cout << "Must provide IP address as argument.\n";
}

Comms_SSL comms;
std::string msg;

std::cout << "Version Number: " << SOME_VERSION_NUM << std::endl;
```

When I run the executable directly from a machine, it works as I expected; It prints out the version number and continues along the program.

When I run this executable remotely via psexec, the execution of the program waits for a carriage return to continue the program AFTER the Tool Version is printed to the console.  At no point in the source code exists a prompt for input of any kind.

The strange thing is, if i change the line that prints the version number to end with '\n':

```
std::cout << "Version Number: " << SOME_VERSION_NUM << '\n';
```

When I run this executable again via psexec, the execution of the program waits for a carriage return to continue the program BEFORE the Tool Version is printed to the console.

I'm at a loss of what's happening here.  I would like to be able to run this program via psexec without requiring a carriage return to continue.

Comment: Are you sure that the program itself blocks until you send a carriage return?  I find it more plausible that it runs to completion, but its output is not (all) forwarded to you until you send a carriage return.  And that would be all psexec, not a C++ issue at all.

Comment: Output buffering is different depending on whether output is to a terminal or some other kind of stream. It looks like `psexec` is not emulating a terminal, so the output is buffered. `std::endl` flushes the buffer.

Comment: Check the documentation of `psexec` to see if there's an option to get a pseudo-tty on the server.

Comment: post the `psexec` command that you are using please, are you using `powershell`?

Comment: @JohnBollinger, how would I check to see if the program has run to completion without the output forwarded to me?

Comment: It depends on what else the program does or can be made to do, @Joe.  Is there some result that can be checked independently of the terminal output?  For example, does it write to a file that you could check via a separate connection to the same machine?  Even if not, my main point is to recommend that you focus first on psexec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, using `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`, the output would be the same, but may not appear in real time. It is because `std::endl` do a `os.flush()`

Second, I will asume that you are using powershell like [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/437504/why-does-psexec-hang-after-successfully-running-a-powershell-script), so is a common problem.
(If not I will delete this post)

And the workaround is to pipe some data on `stdin` with `cmd` and it will return propertly after execution.